# How to change NavigationViewStyle from a descendent view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui

I have a `NavigationView` at the root of my app that has the initial state of `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)`, but as I navigate, I want to change that style to `.doubleColumn.`

From my descendent view I have tried calling `navigationViewStyle(.doubleColumn)` much like how you change the navigation bar title, but no luck.

Trying a ternary operator in the root view also doesn't work `navigationViewStyle(isDoubleColumn ? .doubleColumn : .stack)`

ROOT VIEW:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            //stuff
        }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}
```

Descendent View

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        //stuff
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.doubleColumn) //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No I ended up embedding the view in a UIKit app

Answer (score 5):

DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle is a struct that needs to be initialized. Try it this way:

```
.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below does the job but with the price of losing of some state data so it may not really be the solution.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @State var isDoubleColumn = false

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isDoubleColumn{
                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            } else {
                NavigationView {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert but something tells me that the style can't be changed during NavigationView lifetime.